# Killed commands on terminal startup

Tags: macos, terminal, command, zsh, fig

Each time, when I open a new terminal window, there are thrown a bunch of killed commands.

[Screenshot of the terminal on startup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z02jJ.png)

I did not set up any of them on my own.
I do not know, where are they configured.
In Preferences in command processor section there are no startup commands configured as well.

[Screenshot of Preferences window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fj44a.png)

The issue is how to **make them executable** or how to **remove them**

*I will be grateful, if you help me to resolve it*

Comment: I would first trace the zsh startup to see, which command is actually causing this mess.

Comment: Please don't use screenshots for simple text. Just copy/paste the text into your question. The problem is not that the `mkdir` command is not executable. It's being killed (presumably by the OS kernel) for some reason. Those commands could be in any of several files but the most likely is *~/.zshrc*. What does `echo $HOME` output? Is it your home directory? What happens if you manually run `mkdir -p "${HOME}/.local/bin`?

Comment: @KurtisRader 
1. `% echo $HOME` outputs `/Users/user`
2. `% mkdir -p "${HOME}/.local/bin` prints the following `dquote> `